# Creating dummy filler rows into SQL Table if familyID is not a multiple of 4 to make it so

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in adding dummy filler rows to a SQL Table. The table holds family cards with familyIDs, but I need to add fillers for families that aren't

Below is an example. I'm essentially wanting to add filler rows retaining the familyID to ensure every family is a multiple of 4.

If the family has 3 ppl, I'll add 1 filler
4 ppl do nothing
5 ppl add 3 fillers
1 ppl add 3 fillers etc.

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| FamilyID | FirstName | LastName |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1234     | Janet     | Roberts  |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1234     | Kevin     | Roberts  |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1234     | DUMMY     | DUMMY    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1234     | DUMMY     | DUMMY    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 3423     | Adam      | Lake     |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 3423     | DUMMY     | DUMMY    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 3423     | DUMMY     | DUMMY    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 3423     | DUMMY     | DUMMY    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1111     | April     | Lo       |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1111     | Randy     | Lo       |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1111     | Abby      | Lo       |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1111     | Ray       | Lo       |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1111     | Sandra    | Lo       |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1111     | DUMMY     | DUMMY    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1111     | DUMMY     | DUMMY    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1111     | DUMMY     | DUMMY    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?  Some more sample data with expected results may help.

Comment: you said "If the family were 7 ppl, I would add 1" could you please add this sample output

Comment: @MJH I added more data.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I did one for, if a family is 5 ppl, it needs to have 3 dummys to make it 8

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Is this by any chance because you want to format it in some way? Whats the real problem here?

Comment: What do you mean XY Problem @Nick.McDermaid
I want it formatted so it can be later parsed and grouped into 4's

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

I see.  I'm not sure if you want a `select` query or `insert`.  The following generates the extra rows:

```
select familyid, 'DUMMY', 'DUMMY'
from (select familyid, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by familyid
     ) t join
     (values (1), (2), (3)) as n(n)
     on (cnt % 4) <= 4 - n.n
where cnt % 4 > 0;
```

For a `select` you would use `union all`:

```
insert into t(FamilyId, FirstName, LastName)
    select familyid, 'DUMMY', 'DUMMY'
    from (select familyid, count(*) as cnt
          from t
          group by familyid
         ) t join
         (values (1), (2), (3)) as n(n)
         on (cnt % 4) <= 4 - n.n
    where cnt % 4 > 0;
```

Comment: I'd like an insert!

Comment: If you have one familyID row, this will create 1 extra row, not 3.

Comment: @SQL_M . . . The arithmetic was off.  I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nice one. I was trying an approach with rownumber on the family table and comparing that to a base table with numbers, but couldn't get it working. Plus 1.

Comment: @GordonLinoff For completeness sake, the inner part needs a groupby familyID.

Comment: @SQL_M . . . LOL.  So much for my actually running tests (which I did).